# When undoing a downvote on Area 51, reputation is not re-calculated

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, down-votes

Somebody downvoted my post (on Area 51) and then they changed their mind. They "un-downvoted" it, and the count went back to 0. I had lost two reputation when they downvoted me, but when they "un-downvoted" my post, I didn't get my reputation back. Is this meant to be like this, or is this a glitch? How do I get my reputation back?

**Edit:**
I tried triggering the reputation recalc, and nothing happened.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Area 51 is running on  a very old codebase of Stack Exchange.

Back when it was built, reputation was not calculated when votes were removed, only added.

The only way to synchronize the reputation on Area 51 is to visit [the reputation audit page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/reputation),  scroll to the bottom and click the "Trigger Reputation Recalc" button:

> [image]

---

> ***Note: this will also remove all reputation gained on proposals that have been deleted, even years after it happened. You might lose thousands of reputation by doing that.***

Comment: I did what you said, nothing happened. I added to my question.

Comment: @books453 I'm afraid you have been misled then. I checked now, and the downvote [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101667/google/104131#104131) was never undone. Maybe the one casting it **tried** to change it, but it's not possible to change a vote five minutes after casting it.

Comment: Weird, I remember seeing that the count was at 0

Comment: So the only thing I can think of is that user undoing the vote then casting it back. Final outcome can't be denied: the downvote is there.